# How to query alphanumeric primary key

Tags: php, mysql, alphanumeric

I have this Table called equipments EquipID as primary key set as varchar 4. This column alphanumeric values like:
A101
A102
A103

I am writing a query like below but its not returning anything.

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM equipments WHERE EquipID = \"{$equipment_id}\"";
```

I also did an echo test on $equipment_id to see if holds a value. It show it does.

then I also hardcoded EquipID to see if it works like shown below but it doesn't.

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM equipments WHERE EquipID = 'A101'";
```

I dont know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Assuming you are connected to the correct database and the table and column names are correct, then perhaps there is no record with that equipment id.

Comment: Have you checked same query in `phpmyadmin`?

Comment: It does have record with the value "A101". when i use any other column in WHERE clause like this:       $query = "SELECT *
                FROM 
                equipments
                WHERE
                BrandID = '2'"; it does give me result. i thought it had something to do with the nature of data that it is alphanumeric like "A101"

Comment: it runs fine and returns one row in phpmyadmin

Comment: it definitly should work for varchar and for int. Alphanumeric keys are no problem. It must be somthing else. Maybe your Kollation... Or maybe you are connected with the wrong db.

Comment: Thank you guys for your prompt replies. There was an error in db connection. Its working now.